# How to add new columns in mysql web application

Tags: php, mysql

I want to add a  (ADD column) button in my web application. When i click on add column button it automatically adds a new column in mysql table.

Comment: where is your code and your effort?

Comment: show me your code and ideas ?

Comment: That's certainly a good thing to put in, probably. Where's your issue? Are you trying to get us to do your work for you? Because if so, there are plenty of people available for hire for exactly that reason.

Answer (score 1):

Adding column to table:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
ADD column_name datatype
```